# Ruby update stack from Cedar14 to heroku18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, heroku-api

I recently update my ruby heroku app from stack cedar14 to heroku18 and I'm facing issue that I can't identify. I'm beginner in ruby's app and I'm totaly lost.
My home page display filter and I don't succeed to display them since I changed the stack app.

Here the app in production in cedar14
[App with filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Iypr.png)

Here the app in preproduction in heroku18
[App without filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGC5q.png)

I don't have any error in logs : 
2020-03-30T13:06:34.534548+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/filters" for 87.231.123.63 at 2020-03-30 13:06:34 +0000

2020-03-30T13:06:34.535709+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by FiltersController#getallfilters as JSON

2020-03-30T13:06:34.582362+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/images/spie.svg" for 87.231.123.63 at 2020-03-30 13:06:34 +0000

2020-03-30T13:06:34.584035+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/images/spinner-57f23599cb45c2f22942f6157e01715a.gif" for 87.231.123.63 at 2020-03-30 13:06:34 +0000

2020-03-30T13:06:34.586593+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/fonts/DINPro-Regular_13937.woff" for 87.231.123.63 at 2020-03-30 13:06:34 +0000

2020-03-30T13:06:34.590706+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/spie.svg" host=spie-refcom-preprod.herokuapp.com request_id=98860672-df27-4df1-8bef-c9dc126a21b3 fwd="87.231.123.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=160 protocol=https

2020-03-30T13:06:34.594801+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/fonts/DINPro-Regular_13937.woff" host=spie-refcom-preprod.herokuapp.com request_id=21630fcf-1d62-450c-8883-759f5222df62 fwd="87.231.123.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=160 protocol=https

2020-03-30T13:06:34.675533+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=spie-refcom-preprod.herokuapp.com request_id=a5636f66-ff00-47a6-9461-8da7a764e097 fwd="87.231.123.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https

2020-03-30T13:06:34.591020+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/spinner-57f23599cb45c2f22942f6157e01715a.gif" host=spie-refcom-preprod.herokuapp.com request_id=15f55626-d47d-40ba-a4b7-b4bf808b528e fwd="87.231.123.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=160 protocol=https

2020-03-30T13:06:44.547528+00:00 app[web.1]: Read fragment views/spie-refcom-preprod.herokuapp.com/filters.json (10010.8ms)

2020-03-30T13:06:44.547621+00:00 app[web.1]: on geAllFilters

2020-03-30T13:06:45.438362+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 1

2020-03-30T13:06:45.624412+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 2

2020-03-30T13:06:45.796600+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 3

2020-03-30T13:06:46.104284+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 4

2020-03-30T13:06:46.457596+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 5

2020-03-30T13:06:46.890757+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 6

2020-03-30T13:06:47.848542+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 7

2020-03-30T13:06:48.225331+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 8

2020-03-30T13:06:48.225346+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 9

2020-03-30T13:06:48.609348+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 10

2020-03-30T13:06:48.993956+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 11

2020-03-30T13:06:49.360942+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 12

2020-03-30T13:06:49.722752+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 13

2020-03-30T13:06:50.147104+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 14

2020-03-30T13:06:50.646333+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 15

2020-03-30T13:06:51.193571+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 16

2020-03-30T13:06:51.492277+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 17

2020-03-30T13:06:51.819438+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 18

2020-03-30T13:06:52.138349+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 19

2020-03-30T13:06:52.437847+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 20

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774590+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& after push 21

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774598+00:00 app[web.1]:  &&&&&&&& after push 22

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774599+00:00 app[web.1]: &&&&&&&& END RENDER

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774625+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"1", "name"=>"subsidiary", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["BU0007", "BUSUK", "BUSOGS", "BUSBEL", "BUSNL", "BUSICS", "BUSHQ", "BUOTHER", "BUSCH", "BU0041", "BU0042", "BU0020", "BUDZE", "BU0063", "BU0064", "BU0065", "BU0066"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774630+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"2", "name"=>"customer", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>[], "needTranslation"=>false}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774633+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"3", "name"=>"location", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>[], "needTranslation"=>false}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774677+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"4", "name"=>"client_sector", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["C01", "C02", "C03", "C04", "C05", "C06"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774679+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"5", "name"=>"activity", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["E1", "E2", "E3"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774718+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"6", "name"=>"skill", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["E11", "E12", "E13", "E41", "E42", "E43", "E44", "E45", "E61", "E62", "E63", "E64", "E65", "E66"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774744+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"7", "name"=>"amount", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["<= 100 K€", "100 K€ - 500 K€", "500 K€ - 1 M€", "1 M€ - 3 M€", "3 M€ - 5 M€", "5 M€ - 10 M€", "10 M€ - 20 M€", "> 20 M€"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774764+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"8", "name"=>"duration_range", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["< 1", "1 - 3", "3 - 5", "> 5"], "needTranslation"=>false}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774766+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"9", "name"=>"period_start_end_contract", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>[], "needTranslation"=>false}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774827+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"10", "name"=>"sector_public_private", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["0", "-1"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774828+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"11", "name"=>"account_type", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["CL01", "CL02", "CL03", "CL04", "CL05", "CL06", "CL07", "CL08", "CL09", "CL10"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774833+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"12", "name"=>"contract_type", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["TC01", "TC02", "TC03", "TC04", "TC05"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774854+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"13", "name"=>"phase", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["UP0", "MI0", "DS0"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774857+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"14", "name"=>"service_line", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["AS0", "WS0", "CD0", "EP0"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774917+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"15", "name"=>"prestation", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["AS01", "AS02", "AS03", "AS04", "AS05", "AS06", "AS07", "AS08", "WS01", "WS02", "WS03", "WS04", "WS05", "WS06", "CD01", "CD02", "CD03", "CD04", "EP01", "EP02", "EP03", "EP04", "EP05", "EP06", "EP07", "EP08"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774922+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"16", "name"=>"detail_phase", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["UP01", "UP02", "MI01", "MI02", "DS01", "DS02", "DS03", "DS04", "DS05", "DS06", "DS07", "DS08", "DS09"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774969+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"17", "name"=>"perimeter", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["AUT01", "BI", "DC", "ENVUSR", "IP", "UCC"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.774991+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"18", "name"=>"techno_category", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["AUT01", "BI1", "BI2", "DC1", "DC2", "DC3", "IP1", "IP2", "SEC", "UCC1", "UCC2", "UCC3"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.775006+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"19", "name"=>"das_service", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["CONSEIL & INGENIERIE", "INFOGERANCE", "SERVICES OPERES & CLOUD", "AUTRES SERVICES"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.775044+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"20", "name"=>"service_category", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["AUTRES SERVICES", "CONSEIL& ARCHITECTURE", "INFOGERANCE INFRA", "INFOGERANCE UTILISATEURS", "INGENIERIE PROJET", "MAINTENANCE", "SERVICES MANAGES, HEBERGES, CLOUD", "SERVICES OPERATEUR", "DEP", "INFOG5"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.775048+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"21", "name"=>"strategic_activity_domain", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["TN", "TSE", "M", "DEM"], "needTranslation"=>true}
2020-03-30T13:06:52.775074+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"22", "name"=>"certificate_ability", "className"=>"subsidiary", "choices"=>["true", "false"], "needTranslation"=>true}

2020-03-30T13:06:52.787817+00:00 app[web.1]: [active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::JsonApi (11.09ms)
2020-03-30T13:07:02.799924+00:00 app[web.1]: Write fragment views/spie-refcom-preprod.herokuapp.com/filters.json (10011.6ms)

2020-03-30T13:07:02.800227+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 28264ms (Views: 12.2ms)

2020-03-30T13:07:02.810605+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/filters" host=spie-refcom-preprod.herokuapp.com request_id=528f5bf9-d23e-475b-9e0f-f46974406843 fwd="87.231.123.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=28268ms status=200 bytes=4859 protocol=https

2020-03-30T13:06:02+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-flat-8235 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.095 sample#load-avg-5m=0.11 sample#load-avg-15m=0.095 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15664264kB sample#memory-free=12345944kB sample#memory-cached=1200884kB sample#memory-redis=308928bytes sample#hit-rate=0.42857 sample#evicted-keys=0

2020-03-30T13:06:02+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-flat-8235 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.18 sample#load-avg-5m=0.115 sample#load-avg-15m=0.095 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15664264kB sample#memory-free=12346192kB sample#memory-cached=1200888kB sample#memory-redis=308928bytes sample#hit-rate=0.42857 sample#evicted-keys=0

Here you can find app structure :

[App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RdXm.png)

Here the gem file :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.6.5'

gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '>= 4.2.5.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby 

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'ember-cli-rails'

gem 'restforce'

gem 'responders'

gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0'

gem 'json'

gem 'actionpack-action_caching'

gem 'redis-rails'

gem 'postmark-rails'

gem 'rack-attack'

gem 'tzinfo-data'

# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'puma'
end

gem 'rails_12factor', group: [:staging, :production]
```

Can someone help me??
I know that's not an easy mission :p !

Regards,
Antoine.

Comment: check developer console

Comment: @PGill Hello, can you tell me more ? What do you mean by developer console ?
I'm using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Check [this](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/232313848-How-to-open-the-developer-console)